# Add schema directive for all the queries in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server, express-graphql

1. Is there a way to add a schema directive by overriding one of the methods of [SchemaDirectiveVisitor](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/blob/wip-schema-directives/src/schemaVisitor.ts) **for all the queries and mutations**? For example to check the authentication token in a directive. Would be nice to add it just once not for every query/mutation defined.
2. If yes, which one of the following methods should be overwritten and how? I wasn't able to find an example on how to override each of them.

   - `visitSchema(schema: GraphQLSchema)`
   - `visitScalar(scalar: GraphQLScalarType)`
   - `visitObject(object: GraphQLObjectType)`
   - `visitFieldDefinition(field: GraphQLField<any, any>)`
   - `visitArgumentDefinition(argument: GraphQLArgument)`
   - `visitInterface(iface: GraphQLInterfaceType)`
   - `visitUnion(union: GraphQLUnionType)`
   - `visitEnum(type: GraphQLEnumType)`
   - `visitEnumValue(value: GraphQLEnumValue)`
   - `visitInputObject(object: GraphQLInputObjectType)`
   - `visitInputFieldDefinition(field: GraphQLInputField)`

My intuition would say that `visitObject(object: GraphQLObjectType)` since `type Query` is a `GraphQLObjectType`.

3. What will be the [DirectiveLocation](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#DirectiveLocations) in the end? OBJECT or QUERY/MUTATION?

Answer (score 2):

To visit objects (you are right Query is) use `visitObject` and for specific api end (any method in Query) use `visitFieldDefinition`
I have implemented it in following way,

```
class authDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
    visitObject(type) {
        this.ensureFieldsWrapped(type);
        type._requiredAuthRole = this.args.requires;
    }

    visitFieldDefinition(field, details) {
        this.ensureFieldsWrapped(details.objectType);
        field._requiredAuthRole = this.args.requires;
    }
    ensureFieldsWrapped(objectType){
        const fields = objectType.getFields();
        //your logic to resolve directive
    }
}
module.exports = authDirective;
```

In graphQL shema

```
directive @authorization(requires: Role) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION
```

In schema-builder or server include

```
resolvers,
schemaDirectives: {
    authorization: authDirective
}
```